# Forming Views Depending on The UserName at MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I used ASP.NET configuration and created some users with their roles.
I created controllers to `create/edit/show` details data in a table.
Here is what my create form looks like:
There are two dropdownlists those are named "`Categories`", and "`Users`"."`Categories`" will be selected by the user which is fine."`Users`" is the one that any user is selecting another user and insert into table. That should not be happening.
Here comes my question.
**How can I get rid of the dropdownlist "`Users`" and put the logged in username automatically to be inserted into table?**
---Person A shouldn't be adding a category for Person B!---
In the view this is how the users are put into the dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Userid",String.Empty)
```

I can share  the model code, and the controller code detailed if it is needed.

### Thanks in advance!

Here is my create method:

```
   public ActionResult Create(icerik icerik)
        {
            if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenicated)
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;
    User user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);
}

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.icerik.Add(icerik);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            ViewBag.Kategorid = new SelectList(db.Kategoriler, "Id", "Adi", icerik.Kategorid);
           // ViewBag.Userid = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "UserName", icerik.Userid);

            ViewBag.Userid = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "UserName", icerik.Userid);
            return View(icerik);
        }
```

Here is how I call it in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Userid", String.Empty)
```

How can I get logged in User using session in the controller?

Comment: It's hard from your question to understand what is happening, what you expect to happen, more code might help. More clarity would help more.

Comment: Are you using `FormsAuthentication`?

Comment: Yes,I am using FormsAuthentication by typing [Authorize] also I am using ASP.NET Configuration, users are stored in Users table.UserName is the field that has the user names in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `User` class to get information about the logged in user.

```
if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenicated)
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);
}
```

Now you have the currently logged in user in the `user` variable. You can remove the drop down list for user in the view.

**Edit**
Try this in your `POST` action:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenicated)
    {
        string userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);

        icerik.UserId = user.UserId;        
        db.icerik.Add(icerik);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding.I typed your code in the [HttpPost]Create method however User user = db.Users.First(**user** => user.UserName == userName);
The bold one goes underlined and says "A local variable named 'user' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'user', which is already being used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else."

Comment: @RuhiGoktas ah my bad. That is because I already created an `user` variable above. Rename the variable in bold (in the lambda expression) to `u` or something. Updated my answer too.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(icerik icerik)
        {
            if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenicated)
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;
    User user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);
}
     ....

Comment: @RuhiGoktas yes, does that work? It should not cause that error anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure if I put it it the right place.I've put that in the beginning of the **POST:Create.**
Now It is telling me that 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'XXX.Users' to 'System.Web.Providers.Entities.Users.
Thanks again.

Comment: @RuhiGoktas can you update your question with the code you have in the `POST` action?

Comment: That line **User user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);**
is still giving the same error **"Cannot implicitly convert type XXX.Users' to 'System.Web.Providers.Entities.Users"**.

Comment: @RuhiGoktas try to use the full namespace for `User user`. I.e.: `App.Models.User`. Or just use `var user`.

Comment: Turning it into **var user** fixed the error =} Now Is it going to add the user when I click on create or I need to do something with the view and the model?

Comment: Perfect! THANKS SO MUCH HENK YOU JUST MADE MY DAY!HARTELIJK DANK =]

Answer (score 0):

You can save the logged user's data in cookie or session. You can easily fetch data from cookie or session when you need. There is no need to show drop-down list for users in frontend. From the backend you can fetch data from session or cookie and save it to database. I think this will solve your problem to select the right user.

Comment: how can I get the UserName using session and let it be inserted when I run create method?

Comment: Are you not using an authentication system?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Configuration, users are stored in Users table.UserName is the field that has the user names.

Comment: That's okay. But If you are not using an authentication system or login system I think you will not able to save the data of the right user in session or cookie.

Comment: I am using authentication by typing [Auhtorize]at the beginning of the methods.What I want to get is the logged in username in the controller.

Comment: Then when a user logged in then just keep the userId in the cookie. When you need you can fetch value from cookie like this.
    "var usrId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);"

Comment: Thanks.This seems to be the answer.Do I type this into the [HttpPost] of Create method?

Comment: If you save the userId at the time of login, you can fetch the userId from the cookie anywhere at anytime. You can do this to your "Create" (get/post) action or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can use the following to get the Username, just like you do in the controller

```
@( User.Identity.Name )
```

Then you can remove

```
ViewBag.Userid = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "UserName", icerik.Userid);
```

from the controller and

```
@Html.DropDownList("Userid", String.Empty)
```

from the view

Comment: Thanks I got the username.
Now How can I add it when I click create?